# CreateRendererWithContext (android)

Tags: maui

I am reusing xamarin forms renderer in MAUI. I want to continue using renderer in MAUI. mine is multi project (migtared Xamarin forms to MAUI). i am re using renderers with MAUI compatibility packages.
While creating renderer with "CreateRendererWithContext" method getting exception.

below is my MauiProgram.cs in Android project.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Hosting;

namespace LibraryTestAppMaui.Android
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiAppBuilder builder;
        public static MauiAppBuilder Builder
        {
            get
            {
                if (builder == null)
                {
                    builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
                }

                return builder;
            }
        }
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = Builder;
            builder
                .UseMauiCompatibility()
                .UseMauiApp<App>();

            builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(KeyboardWrapperPage), typeof(KeyboardWrapperPageRenderer));
#endif
            });
            builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

below is my App.Xaml.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Maui;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml;

namespace LibraryTestAppMaui
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static new App Current => (App)Application.Current;

        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           // MainPage = mainPage;
            MainPage = CreateMainPage(new NavigationPage());
        }

        private Page CreateMainPage(NavigationPage navigationPage)
        {
            return new KeyboardWrapperPage(navigationPage);

        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
        }
       
    }
}
```

below is KeyboardWrapperPage

```
using System;
namespace LibraryTestAppMaui
{
    public class KeyboardWrapperPage : Page, IPageContainer<Page>
    {
        public KeyboardWrapperPage(Page innerPage)
        {
            BackgroundColor = Colors.White;

            CurrentPage = innerPage;
            InternalChildren.Add(innerPage);
        }

        public Page CurrentPage { get; }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            return CurrentPage.SendBackButtonPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

below is my KeyboardWrapperPageRenderer in Android.

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
using AndroidPlatform = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.Platform;

namespace LibraryTestAppMaui.Android
{
    public class KeyboardWrapperPageRenderer : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer<KeyboardWrapperPage>
    {
        bool disposed;
        FrameLayout pageContainer;
        IPageController PageController => Element;

        int KEYBOARD_HEIGHT => (int)Context.Resources.GetDimension(260);

        public KeyboardWrapperPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<KeyboardWrapperPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var bottomBarPage = e.NewElement;

                if (pageContainer == null)
                {
                    pageContainer = CreatePageContainer(Context);
                    AddView(pageContainer);

                    RequestLayout();
                }

                UpdateContent();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
            PageController.SendAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
        {
            base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
            PageController.SendDisappearing();
        }

        void UpdateContent()
        {
            pageContainer.RemoveAllViews();

            var page = Element?.CurrentPage;
            if (page != null)
            {
                pageContainer.AddView(GetRenderer(page, Context).View);
               // AddView(Keyboard.KeyboardView);
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && !disposed)
            {
                disposed = true;

                RemoveAllViews();

                var pageRenderer = AndroidPlatform.GetRenderer(Element.CurrentPage);

                if (pageRenderer != null)
                {
                    pageRenderer.View.RemoveFromParent();
                    pageRenderer.Dispose();
                }

                pageContainer?.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        static FrameLayout CreatePageContainer(Context context)
        {
            return new FrameLayout(context)
            {
                LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent, GravityFlags.Fill)
            };
        }

        static IVisualElementRenderer GetRenderer(VisualElement element, Context context)
        {
            var renderer = AndroidPlatform.GetRenderer(element);
            if (renderer == null)
            {
                renderer = AndroidPlatform.CreateRendererWithContext(element, context);
                AndroidPlatform.SetRenderer(element, renderer);
            }

            return renderer;
        }
    }
}
```

i am using KeyboardWrapperPage as MainPage in App.Xaml.cs.

Exception details:

> {Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1 in com.companyname.librarytestappmaui:layout/fragment_backstack: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView  ---> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions  …}  Android.Views.InflateException

Comment: The error message indicates that the `FragmentManager` is already executing transactions when trying to inflate the view. This could happen if you're trying to add, remove, or replace fragments while another transaction is already in progress.

Comment: ok. thanks for the reply. how to solve this.

Comment: You can check this [Mark renderers and related base classes as obsolete](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/5322) and use `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer` instead.

Comment: i am already using this.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer. 
adding the code to my post

Comment: The Renderer has been changed to the handler in the MAUI, it is recommanded that you can convert custom renderer to handler. You can refer to this [article](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/pull/1410) about how to achieve this.